# Change the order of numerically named columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have a dataframe like the one below which has numerical column names

```
example = data.frame(1=c(1,8,3,9), 2=c(3,2,3,3), 3=c(5,2,5,4), 4=c(1,2,3,4), 5=c(2,5,7,8))
```

Which looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 5 1 2
8 2 2 2 5
3 3 5 3 7
9 3 4 4 8
```

And I want to arrange it so that the column names start with three and proceed through five and back to one, like this:

```
3 4 5 1 2
5 1 2 1 3
2 2 5 8 2
5 3 7 3 3 
4 4 8 9 3
```

I know how to rearrange the position of a single column in a dataset, but I'm not sure how to do this with more than one column in this particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the column index concatenated (`c`) based on the sequence (`:`) on a range of values

```
example[c(3:5, 1:2)]
#   3 4 5 1 2
#1 5 1 2 1 3
#2 2 2 5 8 2
#3 5 3 7 3 3
#4 4 4 8 9 3
```

As the column names are all numeric, just convert to `numeric` and use that for ordering

```
v1 <- as.numeric(names(example))
example[c(v1[3:5], v1[1:2])]
```

Or simply do

```
example[c(names(example)[3:5], names(example)[1:2])]
```

Or another way is with `head` and `tail`

```
example[c(tail(names(example), 3), head(names(example), 2))]
```

#### data

```
example <- data.frame(`1`=c(1,8,3,9), `2`=c(3,2,3,3),
   `3`=c(5,2,5,4), `4`=c(1,2,3,4), `5`=c(2,5,7,8), check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`R` will not easily let you create columns with numbers as name. If somehow, you are able to create columns with numbers you can use `match` to get order in which you want the column names.

```
example[match(c(3:5, 1:2), names(example))]

#  3 4 5 1 2
#1 5 1 2 1 3
#2 2 2 5 8 2
#3 5 3 7 3 3
#4 4 4 8 9 3
```